# Concurrent service coordination using Guava Monitor

Tags: java, multithreading, guava

I have a group of services which run concurrently in a thread pool and are managed by a ServiceGroup. They are implemented as Runnables with a closed loop. One of these services is a Validator which must complete at least one loop before the rest of the services can be allowed to start up.

The 'waiting for validation' situation could be resolved with a simple while loop, but I am trying to get a better understanding of the Google Guava Monitors and Guards, wondering if these could be used.

The rough overview of my code is:

```
public class ServiceGroup implements Runnable {

    private ThreadPoolExecutor taskExecutor = ...;
    private Validator validator = ...;
    private final Monitor monitor = new Monitor();

    public void run(){
        taskExecutor.execute(validator);
        monitor.enterWhen(isValidatorRunOnce);
        try{
            taskExecutor.execute(new MyService());
            taskExecutor.execute(new MyService());
            taskExecutor.execute(new MyService());
            doManagementOperations();
        }finally{
            monitor.leave();
        }
    }

    private final Monitor.Guard isValidatorRunOnce = new Monitor.Guard(monitor) {
        @Override
        public boolean isSatisfied() {
            return validator.isValidationRunOnce();
        }
    }
}
```

When the code is executed, the validator gets spinned up. The guard isValidatorRunOnce is called once, returns false as the first validation loop has not finished. Beyond that  the validator keeps running its loops successfully but the main thread just keeps waiting behind the monitor guard, never running the check again and never entering the try/catch block.

I think the problem is that the monitor needs to be notified when the Validator has done its work and the Guard should be re-evaluated? I was expecting for the Guard to keep checking the condition itself with no triggers from my part. I could use any advice on what I am misunderstanding here about the Monitor and how I could better resolve the situation.

Thank you

Comment: I believe you're supposed to enter the monitor whenever you're doing anything that might affect the monitor's status, including executing the validator.

Comment: "wondering if these could be used", yes if validator would `enter()` the monitor. Or you could use a simpler `CountDownLatch` because you don't seem to be using the monitor for anything but as a tool to wait. Or even simpler by using the `Future.get` method you'd have access to when you use submit:  `taskExecutor.submit(..).get()`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - I am confused as to how this should work as the Monitor documentation contains extracts like "Only one thread may occupy a given monitor at any moment". If my main thread has entered the monitor and now needs the validator to finish a task - in another thread - how could the same monitor coordinate this? Perhaps you could provide a simple code example?

Comment: @zapl - yes you are correct - at the moment I am using the monitor just for waiting. I am trying to understand how it works before trying anything more complicated. Future.get probably does not work for me as the services do not end their run - they run continuously in an internal loop. I have not encountered CountDownLatch yet - it might be what I should use - looks promising at any rate. Thanks

Comment: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Monitor.html have you read the Monitor example from its own Javadoc?  Presumably your main thread would `enterWhen` the validator has been run once, which will actually block until the monitor guard becomes true; it'll check to _see_ if the monitor guard becomes true whenever another thread _leaves_ the monitor, so if your validator unconditionally enters the monitor, sets `isValidationRunOnce`, and then leaves the monitor, then the main thread will resume.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes, the Monitor javadoc was what I based my code on and it seemed to lack a code example about interactions between different threads. I must be unaware of some best/normal practices the javadoc assumes the reader to know.

That said, I tried what you suggested and sure enough, if I make the Monitor available to the Validator and call monitor.notifyAll() from there, the code works. I am OK accepting this as a solution but I am quite unhappy about having to pass that monitor instance around. I was hoping for a somewhat more automagic solution.

Comment: The javadoc has 3 equivalent implementations of the same scenario: a box that can hold exactly 1 item where 1 (or more) thread tries to put items and another thread that takes out items. But they must wait on each other, you can not put another before it wasn't taken out and you can not take an item out if the box is empty. So those threads need to signal each other all the time when they are done. Monitor allows to do that without `notifyAll` while the `synchronized` code needs it. Monitor signals automatically in `monitor.leave()`, the other code does it manually before leaving.

Comment: It's also not possible to get proper conditional wait semantics without state-changing code explicitly triggering a synchronization barrier since you can otherwise not guarantee that the waiting code would see the updated condition. Hence passing around a monitor, lock object or something else is required. (The `Future.get` part does that too but you don't see it as much)

Comment: @Tarmo I'm afraid there is no free lunch.  There is no magical solution here.